# can't submit form while using a custom user provider

Tags: php, symfony4

i'm setting up a login system, witch relies on a curl call to another web service to authenticate the user through a login form, for that i followed the documentation by using the maker bundle to generate a custom user provider, a User model, a SecurityController and a LoginFormAthenticator.
the form shows up but don't submit and give no error to help me out for debugging.

according to symfony documentation the support method of LoginFormAthenticator is called each time even before the controllers, indeed when i write a die in it it shows what i put in the die.

besides that, i tried to do it manually by creating the form in the login action and check if submit but the form doesn't submit.
i've been struggling with it since 3 days.

Login form

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
{{ parent() }}
{{ encore_entry_link_tags('login') }}
{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="{{ path('app_login') }}">
{% if error %}
    <div class="alert alert-danger">{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

<h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Connectez vous</h1>
<label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email</label>
<input type="email" value="" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required autofocus>
<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Mot de passe</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Mot de passe" required>

<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"
       value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}"
>

    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">
    Connexion
    </button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Security.yaml

```
security:
    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        logout: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - App\Security\LoginFormAuthenticator
access_control:
      - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

SecurityController.php

```
class SecurityController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @param AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/login", name="app_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils): Response
    {
        // get the login error if there is one
        $error = $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError();
        // last username entered by the user
        $lastUsername = $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername();

        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
        'last_username' => $lastUsername,
        'error' => $error
        ]);
    }
}
```

User Model (since i'm not using Doctrine)

```
class User implements UserInterface
{
    private $email;

    private $roles = [];

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * A visual identifier that represents this user.
     *
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getUsername(): string
    {
        return (string) $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getRoles(): array
    {
        $roles = $this->roles;
        // guarantee every user at least has ROLE_USER
        $roles[] = 'ROLE_USER';

        return array_unique($roles);
    }

    public function setRoles(array $roles): self
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        // not needed for apps that do not check user passwords
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        // not needed for apps that do not check user passwords
    }

    /**
     * @see UserInterface
    */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        // If you store any temporary, sensitive data on the user, clear it here
        // $this->plainPassword = null;
    }
}
```

UserProvider

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {

        // Load a User object from your data source or throw UsernameNotFoundException.
        // The $username argument may not actually be a username:
        // it is whatever value is being returned by the getUsername()
        // method in your User class.
        throw new \Exception('TODO: fill in loadUserByUsername() inside 
         '.__FILE__);
    }


    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Invalid user class 
            "%s".', get_class($user)));
        }

        // Return a User object after making sure its data is "fresh".
        // Or throw a UsernameNotFoundException if the user no longer exists.
        throw new \Exception('TODO: fill in refreshUser() inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return User::class === $class;
    }
}
```

LoginFormAthenticator this is class is supposed to handle every action of the login system

```
class LoginFormAuthenticator extends AbstractFormLoginAuthenticator
{
    use TargetPathTrait;

    private $urlGenerator;
    private $csrfTokenManager;

    public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $urlGenerator, 
       CsrfTokenManagerInterface $csrfTokenManager)
    {
        $this->urlGenerator = $urlGenerator;
        $this->csrfTokenManager = $csrfTokenManager;
    }

    public function supports(Request $request)
    {

        return 'app_login' === $request->attributes->get('_route')
        && $request->isMethod('POST');
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {

        $credentials = [
            'email' => $request->request->get('email'),
            'password' => $request->request->get('password'),
            'csrf_token' => $request->request->get('_csrf_token'),
        ];
        $request->getSession()->set(
            Security::LAST_USERNAME,
            $credentials['email']
        );

        return $credentials;
    }

    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface 
       $userProvider)
    {

        $token = new CsrfToken('authenticate', 
        $credentials['csrf_token']);
        if (!$this->csrfTokenManager->isTokenValid($token)) {
            throw new InvalidCsrfTokenException();
        }

        // Load / create our user however you need.
        // You can do this by calling the user provider, or with custom logic here.
        $user = $userProvider->loadUserByUsername($credentials['email']);

        if (!$user) {
            // fail authentication with a custom error
            throw new CustomUserMessageAuthenticationException('Email could not be found.');
        }

        return $user;
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        // Check the user's password or other credentials and return true or false
        // If there are no credentials to check, you can just return true
        throw new \Exception('TODO: check the credentials inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, 
      TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), 
         $providerKey)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // For example : return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator- 
        >generate('some_route'));
        throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside 
      '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate('app_login');
    }
}
```

Comment: i solved it, since i'm using webpack encore there is a js file in witch i prevent the form submit .